# Is Set-Cookie effective to xhr or fetch?

Tags: ajax, cookies

In a browser a get request is initiated by `fetch('/abc')`. The server responded 200 with header `Set-Cookie: a=b`. Is the cookie in the browser getting set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. You should check the network developer tools tab. Also try checking `document.cookie`.